# GWT adding clickhandlers to panels and elements

Tags: java, gwt

I have a GWT horizontal panel, which I have styled to make it look like a custom `div` with a given height and width (using raw `HTML` is no-no for me here). Now I want to attach a `clickhandler` to it. How do I do it?

Doing something like `mypanel.addClickHandler() {}` is throwing an error stating that I can't attach such event to a panel. Same goes for `mypanel.getElement().addClickHandler() {}`. Is there any way to attach `clickhandler`, `keyuphandler` etc to elements and panels, i.e which are not buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [FocusPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FocusPanel.html) which adds the ability to catch mouse and keyboard events. You can add your `HorizontalPanel` to a `FocusPanel` and then add the required event handlers.

Comment: Ok, so how does `FocuPanel` stack inner panels?

Comment: As it extends `SimplePanel`, it can contain only one widget.

Comment: There is no need to wrap a HorizontalPanel in a FocusPanel if you need to add a ClickHandler.

Comment: Well, that's definitely another solution, but this is also a correct one, so I don't think it merits a downvote.

Comment: @Cupidvogel  Did you consider all the consequences of adding a FocusPanel around your HorizontalPanel? Like tab behavior? It may not hurt in your use case, but generally it's not a good idea to write unnecessary code or add unnecessary widgets.

Comment: @Swapnil, I have a GWT focuspanel which has mousedown and up handler, the problem is the mousedown handler is not calling immediately in my IE11 browser, it always delayed calling, but it works fine in firefox and chrome, do you know why? I have VerticalPanel outside this FocusPanel.

Comment: @typeofprogrammer, I haven't really used GWT since 2013, sorry I won't be able to help you on that one :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a ClickHandler directly to your HorizontalPanel:

```
ClickHandler handler = new ClickHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        // Do something
    }
};
myPanel.addDomHandler(handler, ClickEvent.getType());
```